# Using argparse, how can I require two parameters when a user passes a specific flag?

Tags: python

The script should run as follows with the appropriate output. What is required is that if the script runs with `-s` then `-n` is required. `-n` is not and should not be allowed to be passed (or maybe I can be ignore it?) along with the `-g` option.

```
./script.py enable -g servergroupa
./script.py enable -s servicename -n servername
```

Code:

```
enable = subparsers.add_parser('enable')
enable_mutex = enable.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
enable_mutex.add_argument('-g', '--servicegroupname', help='servicegroup name', metavar='<servicegroup name>')
enable_mutex.add_argument('-s', '--servicename', help='service name', metavar='<service name>')
enable_mutex.set_defaults(func=servicegroup_action)
```

Comment: FWIW, it seems like it would be easier to both program this app (and use it) to just have two sub-commands `enable-group` and `enable-service` that require the correct amount of positional arguments (instead of just `enable`), because as far as I can tell there's not a way to do it the way you want with pure `argparse`.

Answer (score 0):

A few options off the bat:

1) Check the users inputs after parse_args: Check for a -g entry, if one exists and an -n entry exists raise a OptionError (or similar) exception, or like you said simply ignore it.

2) Don't use an -n option: force the user to input 2 values after an -s argument via nargs.

3) If those are all of your arguments, it looks like there will always be either 1 or 2 total after enable. So, don't use any options flags and simply use positional nargs. If there are count 1 assume it is group, if count is 2 assume it is individual with name.